# Disable OpenTelemetry tracing on quarkus for vertx reactive

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x, open-telemetry

I am currently attempting to add openTelemetry tracing to my quarkus project. It is a lambda that reaches out to datasources and does some processing. Currently, we are using reactive pgadmin, but when I try to make queries when using the `quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp` import, I get this error `class io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.tracing.QueryRequest cannot be cast to class io.vertx.core.spi.observability.HttpRequest (io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.tracing.QueryRequest and io.vertx.core.spi.observability.HttpRequest are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @4b3ed2f0)`. This code does not show this error when OpenTelemetry is not included in the pom.xml of this project.

I would like this request to be able to go through, or simply turn off open tracing for vertx requests. However, I have read through the quarkus documentation and am not sure how to do that. One approach I can think of is creating a provider to create the PgPool since there is a `TracingPolicy.IGNORE` that I can perhaps set in the `PGPoolConnectionOptions`.

Here is my code stack:

```
pom.xml
<quarkus-plugin.version>2.6.0.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
Code:

import io.vertx.mutiny.pgclient.PgPool;

@Inject
@ReactiveDataSource("important")
PgPool pool;

pool.preparedQuery(QUERY.sql()).executeAndAwait(...
```

TLDR: How do I turn of tracing on on openetelemetry quarkus stack for vertx queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you mention has been fixed in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/22809 which first became available in Quarkus 2.6.3.Final

Comment: Wow it worked. Thank you! Could you share how you knew that this was fixed in 6.3/how I could figure that out in the future? I went through the PR and my error was not in any of the details. Also, the supposed fix of `@QuarkusMainTest and a @ConfigMapping are involved #22792` did not seem to apply to my issue of OpenTelemetry and Reactive. Is there some process I can take to find that later versions have fixed my issues or was this because of knowledge you gathered by being a part of the core quarkus team? @geoand

Comment: You can see the fix version in milestone of the Pull Request. We take care to apply the proper milestones to issues and pull requests for exactly this reason.